# How to update the values of a column 'Col1' based on a column created after 'Col1' in Pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, apply

I need to create a column A which at the beginning has a fixed value. Afterwards I have to create a columnB that depends on the value of column A. Then I have to create a second row for column A which will depend on the result of column B in the row before. Then the procedure is the same for the following rows.
The problem is that when I ask column A to work with the result of Column B I get a Key Error as column B hasn´t been created.

I have tried with the apply function, and moving the columns around. Also I have tried to initialize Column B with default values and hope that the values will update as the rows are being created, but it seems that Pandas creates first the whole column instead of iterating over the rows.

My DataFrame is much bigger than this and there is many columns in between A and B so I tried to simplify the problem as much as I could.

[image]

Comment: this is a good question, but please update it with example input and expected output

Comment: I tried to put an image with the expected output for a basic example with fixed value = 5 for the first row of column A. Please tell me if you can see it, or if you want me to make a better example. Thanks

Comment: @Esteban do not include images, use text data instead.

Comment: the idea is to basically to fill in the logic like a unit test.  For example, something like: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(20,2))); df.iloc[0,0] = 3`  would be a starting dataframe; add an expected output dataframe with a description of the logic

Comment: @Esteban is this for numerical integration by chance?

Comment: @anon01 no it is not. Thanks

Comment: Without clarification of what’s the dependency to the previous rows, you’d be better off with a for loop.

Comment: @Esteban can you provide numbers instead of "Value dependent on..."?

Comment: @QuangHoang  The dependence is very complex, I have around 40 columns after column A so I can get the first result of column B. And the amount of rows depend on the instance of the problem and can be thousands.

Comment: @Esteban you'll have to simplify conceptually then with a minimum reproducible numerical example. The solution will be completely dependent on everything else you are doing.

Comment: @DavidErickson the numbers wont make any scence because of the complexity of the real problem. A is an amount of a product, of which I calculate the revenue after taxes and many more things so I could get to the first value of Column B. Thank you really much for taking the time

Comment: @QuangHoang would you be willing to help me with the problem if I show and explain the code to you? I really need the help

Answer (score 0):

As commented, without clear dependency, it's really hard to vectorize the operation. We can just use a `for` loop. For that, let's assume that we have two functions:

```
def A_to_B(a_value): return a_value + valueB

def B_to_A(b_value): return b_value + valueA

for i, idx in enumerate(df.index):
    # update A value only if not first row
    if i>0: df.loc[idx, 'A'] = df.loc[df.index[i-1], 'B']

    # update B value
    df.loc[idx, 'B'] = A_to_B(df.loc[idx, 'A'])
```

Comment: Hi Qaung, it was my fault because the example wasnt good. The value of b will not be constant, it depends of the value of column A.

Comment: My problem is that for df['A'] I have to necessary use df['B'] for the operation because is not a constant value.